# I create a new KMM project in Android studio and don't see the androidMain module in Android View

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I've spent an entire day trying to solve it, tried to open few projects from github, tried Android studio 4.0, 4.2 canary, IntellyJ Idea but still don't see the androidMain in modules

What should I try?

[image: Screenshot from Android studio]

Comment: Switch to `Project View`

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to see it in the Android mode?

Comment: Actually I don't know, I always use the `Project View`. Let's see if someone else knows if it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding additional [source sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) for your android project by setting in your `shared:build.gradle.kts` file under the `android` node this

```
sourceSets {
    getByName("main") {
        java.srcDirs("src/androidMain/kotlin")
        res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    }
    getByName("test") {
        java.srcDirs("src/androidTest/kotlin")
        res.srcDirs("src/androidTest/res")
    }
}
```

so you could have something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        getByName("main") {
            java.srcDirs("src/androidMain/kotlin")
            res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
        }
        getByName("test") {
            java.srcDirs("src/androidTest/kotlin")
            res.srcDirs("src/androidTest/res")
        }
    }
}
```

This way you could see the `androidMain` and `androidTest` kotlin files under your `MyApplication11` node

[image]